# iterate through php array and create a span

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array of items that I'm trying to traverse through to place on the screen. I can traverse the array just fine but I'm also trying to use span to display the item. I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        foreach($itemsArray as $item)
        {
            '<span class="item '.$team.'">'.img('it', $item).'</span>'
        }
```

I can display the items by just calling the item name, but I would really like to traverse an array of items as the way that it is displayed on the website isn't the way that I would like if I call them separately.

This is how I was doing it before.

```
<span class="item '.$team.'">'.img('it', $item0).'</span>
```

Comment: `echo [... your string ...];` ?!

Comment: Shouldn't the line in your loop be "echo ..."

Comment: @Osuwariboy: depends on if `img()` does output or returns a string... if it's output, then echo won't help and in fact produce bad html

Comment: what can img return then, do you have an example?

Comment: It's supposed to be a 40x40 image icon

Comment: There's a mismatch between the two $item references, in the foreach, you have $items and in the img() you have $item. Is this normal?

Comment: @Osuwariboy I noticed that and fixed it, but still nothing.

Comment: By "nothing", what do you mean exactly? You get a blank output? If it's blank, does putting "echo" in front of your line changes something?

Comment: When I use the foreach the website stops working.

Comment: Can you add what's contained in the $itemsArray variable as well as what is the EXACT return of the img() function to your post?

Comment: @Osuwariboy I was able to figure out my mistake. Simple little misspell in the code above :*( Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

try to use a for loop,if you get confused,

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($itemsArray);$i++)
    {
        '<span class="item '.$team.'">'.img('it', $itemsArray[$i]).'</span>'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue. The issue wasn't with that piece of code.

```
    $itemsArray = array();
    $itemsArray[$i] = $item0;
```

I was using `$array = $item0;`